# How to add new parameter to existing SSRS Report

Tags: visual-studio-2013, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to add a new Parameter called CorporateIdentity to the SalesInvoice report in dynamics. I've added the parm***() method to SalesInvoiceContract and compiled the Contract, the Controller and the DataProvider forward.

But I can't get the parameter to show up in Visual Studio. I've tried refreshing the DataSources. I've tried deleting and recreating one of the DataSources. I've tried to create the Parameter manually.

How can I get this parameter to show up?

Comment: Getting things to show up can sometimes mean standing on one foot and balancing a plate on your head...it's a pain. Have you performed an incremental CIL? Did you try refreshing your caches (Tools>Caches, just do all of them)? Try restarting the AOS service and the SSRS service. Is your WCF data up to date in your AXC file? Try clearing your usage data and AUC/KTI files. There are all sorts of weird things to try, but I listed them in order of what I would try...no need to do them all if one step works.

Comment: @AlexKwitny: the incremental CIL did the trick, Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll make an answer so you can close the question out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to perform an incremental CIL. Some other things to try are listed below.

- Have you performed an incremental CIL?
- Did you try refreshing your caches (Tools>Caches, just do all of them)?
- Try restarting the AOS service and the SSRS service.
- Is your WCF data up to date in your AXC file?
- Try clearing your usage data and AUC/KTI files.

There are all sorts of weird things to try, but I listed them in order of what I would try ... no need to do them all if one step works.